# css stopped working asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

I am reposting the question, since it has changed a lot since I had problems with it initially, I know where the problem is but i do not know how to fix it, or the cause of it at all.

So i have 2 master files, one is for a login page and another one for the inside content. I also have a default.aspx file and a logout.aspx file. They both use the MasterPage.master which is the initial page. What i found out is, when I exclude the Logout.aspx from the project and run it, the website initial page uses the .css file. When I include the logout.aspx debug the program, the initial screen uses the .css at first then when i log in and log out, it shows the default.aspx without the .css. If I try to debug the page again, then the initial screen no longer uses the .css.

My master class has this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <div class="login">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="header">
                   <h1 id="site-name">
                        <font color="black" size="5">SES Users Admin</font>
                   </h1>
                </div>
                 <!--Hello Content -->
                <div class="content">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" Height="21px" 
                            style="margin-left: 2px" Width="133px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br /><br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Height="20px" 
                            style="margin-left: 4px" Width="133px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br /><br />
                        <div class="button">
                        <asp:label id="lblResult" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:label>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnlogin_Click" 
                                Width="57px" Height="21px"/>
                        </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default aspx and default.cs are both empty like so:

```
   <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
        CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

    <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="head">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="MainerContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    </asp:Content>
```

As well as logout except for the logout.aspx.cs which contains the logout function:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Logout.aspx.cs" Inherits="Logout" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="head">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="MainerContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

</asp:Content>
```

CS

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using HelloApp;

public partial class Logout : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");

    }
}
```

Comment: btw what do you mean by "It uses the other one fine" ? do you have another .css file that you were using?

Comment: Never mind, fixed it myself. After deleting the .css file and putting an individual style tag into default.aspx and deleting the master file =_=

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at browser requests in [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) / [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) / [charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to see what's happening to the request for the CSS file.

Comment: I would like to avoid downloading unnecessary programs, is there any other way?

Comment: Incidentally, the above are not 'unnecessary' programs, they are pretty much essential for all jobbing web developers.

Comment: @Angela - Try to build your program without using VS's debugger and you'll get a sense of just how "unnecessary" firebug and the like actually are. Don't think of it as "another program" (and Firebug, at least, isn't technically a program, but an extension to one you should already have), but rather as an HTML/CSS debugger, which is what it is.

Comment: To say that an HTTP tracer/monitor is "unnecessary", when you're in the business of delivering websites over HTTP is plain ridiculous. You can either post on forums and ask people to guess what the problem is, or you can stop placing idiotic constraints on yourself and get the right diagnostic tools to do your job properly.

Comment: Just so you know, I tried using the diagnostic tools, they did not provide me with any useful information. I fixed the problem the old fashioned way, delete and replace :) Thank you for your advice guys tho.

Answer (score 1):

Try viewing the source of a page on the site and look for the `<link ...>` tag. What css file does it point to?

Comment: Looking at the source it seems to be saying the same thing <link href="Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: Does Site.css live in the root of your directory or a subfolder? Use an absolute url e.g.  href='/Site.css' (if the css file is in the root) or href='/css/Site.css' or whatever if its not. It looks to me like the location your link's href attribute is telling the browser the CSS file is located at is not where it actually is ...

Comment: the .css is in the same directory as the master file that uses the .css and as I mentioned before the directory is not the problem because it used to work fine :(

Comment: and what is that directory called?

If its in a folder called say '/master/' try using '/master/Site.css' in your link tag.

Comment: Well the MasterPage.master and the Site.css are both located in a folder called \Project

Comment: Try it with this:
- 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Project/Site.css" />

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your solution explorer? Upload it to www.ploader.net and paste the link here.

Comment: http://www.ploader.net/files/ec18888c790bd1e6c84542b293082645.png  I renamed the site.css just in case it might have been an issue with that, but that didn't help. Although it worked for a bit after i refreshed (read update)

Comment: Thanks for posting. So you've renamed site.css -> Stylesheet.css? OK so try changing the href of the link tag to '/StyleSheet.css'.

Comment: Another thing - You have 2 Master pages. Do they both make use of the SAME stylesheet? Might be worth checking this and ensuring the href points in both points to the same stylesheet file. Also look to see which Master page the pages you are testing actually use.

Comment: those master pages work for different things, one is for the login page, and the other one works as an inside page for the admin. They use different .css files aswell. I got it actually working now. I found the source of the problem but have no idea how to fix it. Apparently, i have a file called logout.aspx, i excluded it from the project. When I run it, it works perfect. When I include the logout.aspx and when I go login then logout, the thing stops using the .css :/

Comment: When you check the source (with logout.aspx included) of the link, what does the href point to?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your `Site.css` is not in the same folder as your MasterPage/ContentPage.

If your link to the stylesheet is simply `Site.css` then what ever the folder your MasterPage/ContentPage or just the ContentPage is in will be looking for the stylesheet in that folder.

e.g. if using `<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Site.css" />`

```
/Folder1/ContentPage.aspx will be looking for /Folder1/Site.css
```

If you change your stylesheet to using `<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Site.css" />` Then your website will look for the stylesheet in the root directory. HOWEVER, if your website is running as

`http://localhost:1234/WebsiteFolder/ContentPage'

"WebsiteFolder", then having `/Site.css` will look for the css file outside of the "WebsiteFolder"

Please post the folder structure of your site, also whether your site is running with a Virtual Path. To find the Virtual Path, view the properties for the website.

Comment: C:\Users\hello\Project is where my project is located. It is running as http://localhost:1234/Project/Default.aspx  Default.aspx is running with MasterPage.master which is located in the folder Project along with Site.css and Default.aspx

Comment: so you have `C:\Users\hello\Project\Default.aspx`, `C:\Users\hello\Project\MasterPage.master`, and `C:\Users\hello\Project\Site.css`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<link href="~/Site.css" runat="server" id="link1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

instead of

```
<link href="Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

after that css loads properly and works fine....

Comment: As i mentioned before, i do not think the problem is with the directory, because I didnt move either files and before it stopped using the .css file, it was working fine.